# How can I merge multiple sheets of an excel workbook in r?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, merge, google-sheets

Let's say I have an excel file called report.xlsx. This file has 10 sheets, conveniently named Sheet1 through Sheet10. On each sheet, on row 14 there are the column headers: S/N, RegistryNr, Surname, FirstName, (empty), FatherName, MotherName, sex, (empty), DOB. How can I merge every sheet into one dataset?

I know that with `excel_sheets("report.xlsx")` I can get all the sheet names into a vector.

I know that with `df <- read_excel("report.xlsx", 1, skip = 14)` I can get all the data of one sheet into data frame df.

That's the extent of my knowledge in R :/

How do I combine the above commands to import every sheet into the same data frame?

Comment: Just write a for loop that loops through the sheets, something like `(for i in 1:14) { df <- rbind(df, read_excel("report.xlsx", i, skip=14)) }`

Comment: @ytk Thanks! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 13):

I routinely do this using purrr and readxl:

```
library(purrr)
library(readxl)

file <- 'path to report.xlsx'

sheets <- excel_sheets(file)

df <- map_df(sheets, ~ read_excel(file, sheet = .x, skip = 14))
```

Comment: I get error `Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : corrupt data frame`

Comment: Having the NA in your headers might be causing the issue.

Comment: @JakeKaupp how would this work if you also want to skip the last row in each sheet? My last row in each sheet is a sum.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
library(foreach)

xls.files = dir(pattern = "xls")

l = foreach(i = 1:length(xls.files)) %do% {

  f = read_excel(xls.files[i])
  setDT(f)

  f[, label := xls.files[i]]

}

rbindlist(l)
```

(the advantage of foreach is that you can set up a parallel backend).